# How to trim the GStreamer registry?

Tags: c, alsa, gstreamer

My registry.arm.bin is 600 KB large, and every time my application starts, it takes  ~ 0.25 seconds to read and parse it.
The problem is that i don't need all the plugins that are located there.
I only want almost all of the plugins for AUDIO, and none for VIDEO.

How can i trim down my registry, so i reduce it size and loading time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the plugins you don't need from your system. They are in /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10 (or -1.0).